# Spring-mvc won't bind my request parameter to int

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have this form with the parameter `year` and `name`:

```
/register?year=&name=test
```

My class looks like this:

```
public class Organizer {
   private String name;
   private int year;
```

My controller maps those two parameters to my class `Organizer`

```
@RequestMapping("/register")
public String register(@Valid Organizer organizer, BindingResult errors...
```

The problem is binding the parameter **year** to int. Spring gives me the error

> Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int' for property 'year'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:

I figured out how to add my own custom property editor, but `getValue()` never seems to be called

```
@InitBinder
public void binder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(int.class, new CustomIntEditor());
}

public class CustomIntEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {
```

I thought I would be able to return the `int` value `0` when the year parameter was anything other than an `int` value (`Integer.parseInt()` -> catch exception)

```
@Override
public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {

    //Some parsing and error handling
    setValue((int)0);
}
```

I would like to be able to:

- Set the field `year` to `int` value `0`
- Create a custom error message : `organizer.year.invalid`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change `int` to `Integer`. This is an auto-boxing issue. Since `year` is empty, it can't be converted to a primitive value (as you have not specified a default value).

Then you can annotate it `@NotNull` to get the validation you want.

Comment: Yes that worked! Thought I could find a way to get it to work with just int

Comment: I think what you were initially looking for was a `ConversionService` (`binder.setConversionService(...)`), not a `CustomEditor`. A ConversionService that could convert from String to Integer, setting the Integer to 0 if the String is empty. I prefer to use non-primitive types instead as it makes the whole thing moot :)

Comment: Yes, Conversion was the feature I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

first , try to run your application in debug mode and find out exact line at which it's throwing error and provide exact details
I think there must be a problem with your datatype (declaration in form)
If you are using hibernate ,check your hibernate entity class.

and check for datatype of year attribute.